# Updating Static label in wxpython on event trigger

Tags: python, event-handling, wxpython

I am building an application that will show basic info about a motorcycle such as RPM and the gear it is in. Say we change gear with a "keyboard button press", how could I get it to update the label. Suppose the equivalent key would be the UP key to go up, so far this is what I came up with but the label wont update when the event is being triggered. What may I be doing wrong?

```
import wx
import sys

var =int(sys.argv[1])
gr = "N" 

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.gauge_1 = wx.Gauge(self, wx.ID_ANY, 10000, style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL | wx.GA_SMOOTH)
        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnKeyUp)
        
        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("Test")
        self.gauge_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(216, 216, 191))
        self.gauge_1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(128, 0, 206))
        self.gauge_1.SetFont(wx.Font(11, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, "Ubuntu"))
        self.gauge_1.SetValue(var)

    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(self.gauge_1, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        label_1 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "GEAR")
        label_1.SetMinSize((100, 50))
        label_1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 137, 215))
        label_1.SetFont(wx.Font(25, wx.FONTFAMILY_MODERN, wx.FONTSTYLE_ITALIC, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, ""))
        sizer_1.Add(label_1, 0, wx.ALL, 3)
        Gearind = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, gr, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        Gearind.SetMinSize((50, 43))
        Gearind.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(122, 0, 7))
        Gearind.SetFont(wx.Font(32, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_SLANT, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, ""))
        sizer_1.Add(Gearind, 0, 0, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()


    def OnKeyUp(self, evt):
        code = evt.GetKeyCode()
        
        if code == wx.WXK_UP:
            gr = "1"
            self.Gearind.SetLabel(gr)
        elif code == wx.WXK_DOWN:
            evt.Skip()



class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self): 
        self.Test = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.Test)
        self.Test.Show()
        return True



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe a `Frame` accepts characters.
Use a `wx.Window` with style `wx.WANTS_CHARS` or a `wx.Panel`

It won't help that you want to update `self.Gearind` but you defined it as a `local` i.e. `Gearind`.

Below, I've added a panel and a few other tweaks (note the gauge value).

You might want to investigate the wxpython `SpeedMeter` which may add some `Vroooom!` to your program.

```
import wx
import sys

try:
    var =int(sys.argv[1])
except Exception:
    var = 0
gr = "N" 

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.gauge_1 = wx.Gauge(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 6, style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL | wx.GA_SMOOTH)
        
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.OnKeyUp)
        
        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("Test")
        #self.gauge_1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(216, 216, 191))
        #self.gauge_1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(128, 0, 206))
        #self.gauge_1.SetFont(wx.Font(11, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, "Ubuntu"))
        self.gauge_1.SetValue(var)

    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(self.gauge_1, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        label_1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "GEAR")
        label_1.SetMinSize((100, 50))
        label_1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(0, 137, 215))
        label_1.SetFont(wx.Font(25, wx.FONTFAMILY_MODERN, wx.FONTSTYLE_ITALIC, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, ""))
        sizer_1.Add(label_1, 0, wx.ALL, 3)
        self.Gearind = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, gr, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.Gearind.SetMinSize((50, 43))
        self.Gearind.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(122, 0, 7))
        self.Gearind.SetFont(wx.Font(32, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_SLANT, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, ""))
        sizer_1.Add(self.Gearind, 0, 0, 0)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()


    def OnKeyUp(self, evt):
        code = evt.GetKeyCode()
        gr = self.Gearind.GetLabel()
        if gr.isnumeric():
            gr_up = int(gr) + 1
            gr_down = int(gr) - 1
        else:
            gr_up = 1
            gr_down = 0
        if gr_up > 6:
            gr_up = 6
        if gr_down < 1:
            gr_down = "N"
        if code == wx.WXK_UP:
            self.Gearind.SetLabel(str(gr_up))
        elif code == wx.WXK_DOWN:
            self.Gearind.SetLabel(str(gr_down))
        gr = self.Gearind.GetLabel()
        if gr == "N":
            var = 0
        else:
            var = int(gr)        
        self.gauge_1.SetValue(var)
        evt.Skip()



class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self): 
        self.Test = MyFrame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.Test)
        self.Test.Show()
        return True



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image][image]